# Does the word "clin" has other usage than "clin d'oeil" ?

Tags: sens, usage

Does the word "clin" has other usage than "clin d'oeil" ? Or is it only related to the eye.

Comment: Je ne crois pas. D'ailleurs Georges Perec a utilisé cette particularité dans son roman [La Disparition](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Disparition_%28roman%29), où il pouvait écrire _clin_ sans autre précision. Un autre mot qu'il utilise est _fur_ dans _au fur et à mesure_.

Comment: Also used in "Bordages à clin", "Bateau à clins" for example and is also an acronym: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clin. Other usages might be possible.

Answer (score 4):

Larousse also says "Biseau formé à l'extrémité de chacune des douelles du tonneau".

Which is "Bevel formed at the end of each of the cask staves".

I just learned it as I answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it has to do with the verb **cligner** [*des yeux*] (to blink), which then gives the noun **clin**.
As @MorganFR pointed out, it is possible that it could refer to something else in a specific field (such as boat building).

Comment: More than that, it applies to any construct similar to the tile layout of a roof, like window blinds, boats, eyes and more.

Answer (score 2):

There are two homonyms spelled [*clin*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/clin).

One is common and only used in the *clin d'œil* / *clin d'yeux* expressions. It comes from *cligner*.

The other one is quite rare and belongs in the ship building and similar vocabulary and means some kind of overlapping tiles. It comes from the Dutch *klinken*, meaning *riveter*/*boulonner* (to rivet/to bolt).